# What's the meaning of square brackets in XCTAssertEqual(expression1: [T : U], expression2: [T : U])?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write a wrapper for XCTAssertEqual, but don't understand the meaning of the brackets.

Comment: I would assume that that is a dictionary.

Comment: @TroyT When I use XCTAssertEqual, I usually place myFuncToTest(input0, input1...) as expression1. Is that a dictionary?

Comment: There are 5 or 6 declarations for XCTAssertEqual, so that's probably not the one you are using for that case.

Comment: You are correct. I'm actually using XCTAssertEqual(expression1: T?, expression2: T?). That can be almost anything. I'd better dig broader next time. You can reply the question with your first comment and I'll pick that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[T : U]` means a dictionary. However, there are 5 or 6 `XCTAssertEqual` methods (depending on how you count, there is a `XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy` method). You are probably meaning to use some other form of `XCTAssertEqual`.